# How can get all data after query search data using mongoose-paginate?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

[image]My query string search is okay but only problem is when remove and display all data...:-(

My code is here

```
  router.get('/allStudents', async (req,res) => {

  const limit = parseInt(req.query.limit, 4) || 4;
  const page = parseInt(req.query.page, 10) || 1;

  const PAGE_SIZE = 10;
  const skip = (page - 1) * PAGE_SIZE;

  try {

       const stdID = await Student.paginate({stdID: req.query.stdID}, {limit, page, 
        skip}) //OK it works!!! but as its remove it wont display the whole data (data:[])

       return res.status(200).json({
         success: true,
         data: stdID
       })
  
  } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
  }

  });
```

Comment: what did you remove  ?

Comment: When Im searching some data it works but Im removing the search and the all data not display

Comment: add some condition , if you remove search keyword or variable , your code run another MongoDB query with match part of  {} means all data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add condition for search

```
 router.get('/allStudents', async (req,res) => {

  const limit = parseInt(req.query.limit, 4) || 4;
  const page = parseInt(req.query.page, 10) || 1;

  const PAGE_SIZE = 10;
  const skip = (page - 1) * PAGE_SIZE;

  try {
       if (req.query.stdID.length >= 0){ // or (req.query.stdID!==null || req.query.stdID!== undefined) 
       const stdID = await Student.paginate({stdID: req.query.stdID}, {limit, page, 
        skip}) //OK it works!!! but as its remove it wont display the whole data (data:[])
    }
      else {
const stdID = await Student.paginate({}, {limit, page, 
        skip})
       return res.status(200).json({
         success: true,
         data: stdID
       })}
       
  
  } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
  }

  });
```

Comment: To be sure you should also add a check if `stdID` exists at all, otherwise you'll get a "..cannot read property length of undefined". But other than that +1 :)

Comment: I add more comment to my code , thank you

Answer (score 1):

What @mohammad Naimi answered is right, but to explain it in layman terms -->

When you pass data you get `stdID` in `req.query` so your mongo query works just fine as you said, but when you are removing all data ,it makes the `req.query.stdID` a null field which causes the error as there is no `req.query`.

you can pass it as shown by Mohammad above or also using Ternary operators.

`let mongoQuery = req.query.stdID ? {stdID: req.query.stdID} : {} ;`

and pass the `mongoQuery` in your paginate function.

Comment: But it wont work :-(

Comment: This should work as far as my understanding goes.
`const stdID = await Student.paginate(mongoQuery, {limit, page, 
        skip})`

you can check the syntax again maybe but this will definitely work, its the same as the answer for this thread. Just a different approach.

you just need to make sure you deal with req.query.stdID in some way for both conditions i.e when its empty AND when its no empty.

Comment: ok Im try this one but is not working
thank you for helping

Comment: sure no worries!

Comment: YES FINALLY I"M SOLVED THIS PROBLEM FOR THE VERY 3 days
THanks for helping me out